# How To Extract a Text String After a specific word in Excell

Tags: excel, uipath

How To Extract  a Text String After a specific word in Excell.
Eg:
Java throw keyword Example
Example 1: Throwing Unchecked Exception

From the Above Notes Need to extract the String after the Example 1: .

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want, there are two options:

1. Search and replace. Select the column where you want to extract the string. CTRL+H then enter in what to replace: *Example 1:
   Replace by leave empty. Then it will remove the string in front.
2. use a formula. you can use LEFT, RIGHT and LEN to determine what to show. For example if you always want to remove the first 8 characters, but the rest of the string could be longer, you can use =RIGHT(reference to cell;LEN(reference to cell)-8))

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your example is in cell A1:

```
=mid(A1,find(":",A1,1)+1,len(A1))
```

will get the text after the "Example:"

Or you could be more specific:

```
=mid(A1,find("1:",A1,1)+3,len(A1))
```